# How do I verify that a function is a PDF in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to verify that a function is a pdf, i.e. that it has the following properties:
1) the integral of f(x) from -infinity to infinity is 1,
2) f(x) > 0 for all x.
Additionally, I am also trying to plot a cdf function.

Here is my function in R script:

```
f <- function(x) ifelse(x>=-1 & x<=1, 1-abs(x), 0)
curve(f, -5, 5)
```

I have tried various things to find the density, but can't seem to write a script that will tell me that 1) the probability X is equal to one, and 2) all values are > 0. I tried writing some of the "d" functions on this page (http://ww2.coastal.edu/kingw/statistics/R-tutorials/prob.html) but can't format them correctly. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you know the domain of your function, i.e. the set of values that it is defined on?

Comment: Sorry, wasn't respecting the beginning of the `ifelse`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to verify that a function is a pdf exactly, except in a few special cases. However, you can do it approximately if you have a good idea what the support of the function is (i.e. the set of values on which the function is nonzero, or nearly nonzero).

For example, take the `dnorm` function, i.e. the standard normal pdf. This is effectively zero outside of -40 and +40. You can create a sample domain with, say, 10,000 points, by doing

```
> xs <- seq(-40, 40, len=10000)
```

Then checking that all values are greater than or equal to zero is as simple as

```
> all(dnorm(xs) >= 0)
TRUE
```

To check that the function integrates to (approximately) 1, you can do

```
> integral <- integrate(dnorm, lower=-40, upper=40)
> abs(integral$value - 1) < 1e-10
TRUE
```

So you can have some confidence that the function `dnorm` describes a probability distribution on the range (-40, 40).

To check the function that you define in your question, clearly the range is (-1, 1) so you can do

```
> xs <- seq(-1, 1, len=10000)
> all(f(xs) >= 0)
TRUE
> integral <- integrate(f, lower=-1, upper=1)
> abs(integral$value - 1) < 1e-10
TRUE
```

So your function looks likely to be a pdf.